# How can I execute a platform independent Java code on an Android device?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a Java application about time synchronization but I only have 2 computers.
I want to try it on my Android devices as well but I don't know how to do it.
Is it possible to run a Java app on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed your non UI java code into an Android Activity to test logic and stuff.
But running it without change is not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by that? It depends heavily on the code you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

The Android platform supports a subset of the Java SE class libraries.  If your "platform independent" application uses only classes in that subset, you should be fine.  Otherwise, you may have difficulties ... depending on what the missing classes are.  (For instance, if you want to use AWT or Swing classes, you are out of luck.)

The simple way to check would be to make a list of all the `java.*` packages that your code depends on, and compare that with the package list in the [Android javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html).

---

You would also need to wrap your code in some kind of skin to make it into an Android `Activity` ... or whatever.  Android doesn't support Java SE style `main(String[])` entry points.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean running a pure Java SE, EE or ME application on an Android device, it is not possible if you try to use classes that are not included in Android.

The language used to program Android is Java, but Android itself doesn't use a direct (perfect match) implementation of any of the above.

Comment: Java SE in particular